# Change View Focus android xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am using Listview inside the Scroll view. and this Listview is the last item of scroll view. Problem is when data gets load the scroller move down to the bottom. How can i prevent it from scrolling on loading data.

Comment: You should not use a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: your listview scroll will contradict with the scroll view itself. you will have a hard time scrolling. goodluck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a ListView inside a ScrollView as they are both scrollable.

However to solve your problem I guess you should use the attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for your main container which resides in the ScrollView.